# Divide the video upload div and URL link div to two web page using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, video

[image]

**HELP ME! I'm having trouble debugging this web-prog**
I wanted to divide the 'upload' div and 'url' div into two pages.

This is my orginal code.

video.php this is where my input file and submit is, plus the url div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>
  Video Upload
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <?php
  include 'video_connect.php';
  ?>
  <div id="box">
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <?php

      if (isset($_FILES['video'])) {
        $name = $_FILES['video']['name'];
        //echo $name."<br>";
        $type = explode(".", $name);
        $type = end($type);
        //echo $type."<br>";
        $size = $_FILES['video']['size'];
        $random_name = rand();
        $temp = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];

        //add to database
        if ($type != "mp4" && $type != "MP4") {
          $message = "Video format not supported!";
        } else {
          move_uploaded_file($temp, "videos/". $random_name. '.' .$type);
          mysql_query("INSERT INTO videos_upload  VALUES('','$name','$random_name.$type')");
          $message = "Successfully uploaded";
        }
        echo "$message <br> <br>";
      }
      ?>
      Select Video: <br>
      <input type="file" name="video">
      <br> <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id='box'>
    <?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,url FROM videos_upload");
    while ($run = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
      $video_id =  $run['id'];
      $video_name = $run['name'];
      $video_url = $run['url'];
      ?>
      <a href="view.php?video=<?php echo $video_url; ?>">
      <div id="url">
        <?php
        echo $video_name;
        ?>
      </div>
      <?php
    }
    ?>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my connectivity to database:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db( "catering_info");
?>
```

and lastly, this the page after you click the url in the video.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>
  Video Upload
  </title>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.19.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
  include 'video_connect.php';
  ?>
  <div id="box">
    <?php
    $video = $_GET['video'];
    ?>
    <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg" data-setup="{}">
      <source src="videos/<?php echo $video; ?>" type='video/mp4'>
      <p class="vjs-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
        <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
      </p>
    </video>
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.19.2/video.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Problem description could be better... What is the problem exactly? Is there errors in console?

Comment: The problem is that whenever I try to divide the 'upload' and 'url' div nothing comes up. No result

Comment: I see syntax errors in this script. *1)* `id` must be unique. You use `<div id="url">` in a `while` loop... So for sure, you have multiple times this `id`. *2)* `<div id="box">` is also duplicate and not closed in "the page after". **Use `class` instead, since it looks like to be used for styling. *3)* You use `mysql_query`, which is deprecated since 2009. Look for mysqli or PDO instead -- Fix that and see if there still is a problem. If there is, be more specific then *«nothing comes up»*.